# My Bubble Sort won't work

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I had a programming assignment given to me to recreate sorting algorithms, well they all seem to do just fine except my Bubble Sort. I have been looking at this code and I just cannot seem to figure it out. I'm hoping you guys can see where I am going wrong. In the book I'm given the psuedocode:

```
BubbleSort(list,N)
//list is the elements to be put in order
// N is the number of elements in the list
numberOfPairs = N
swappedElements = true
while(swappedElements) do         
  numberOfPairs = numberOfPairs-1
  swappedElements = false
  for(i = 1 to numberOfPairs) then
    if(list[i] >list[i+1])then
      swap(list[i], list[i+1]
      swappedElements = true
    end if
  end for
end while
```

ok so thats what I'm given. So then I create this class:

```
public class Bubble_Sort {

    private int[] unsorted;
    private int number;
    private int compareCount = 0;
    private int swapCount = 0;
    private boolean swap = true;

    public void sort(int[] unsorted) {
        this.unsorted = unsorted;
        while (swap) {
            swap = false;

            for (int j = 1; j <= unsorted.length - 1; j++) {
                if (unsorted[j - 1] < unsorted[j]) {
                    compareCount++;
                    swap(j - 1, j);

                    swap = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j) {
        swapCount++;
        int num = unsorted[i];
        unsorted[i] = unsorted[j];
        unsorted[j] = num;
    }

}
```

This is what it outputs for some random array from 0 to 600:

```
Unsorted List: [217, 207, 169, 124, 409, 304, 370, 232, 179, 409, 447, 134, 579, 228, 216, 452, 171, 55, 544, 518, 197, 10, 44, 416, 394, 161, 573, 399, 5, 394, 424, 303, 368, 508, 9, 178, 372, 296, 289, 391, 255, 386, 50, 491, 450, 329, 114, 405, 113, 512, 175, 206, 341, 586, 255, 216, 539, 258, 325, 94, 520, 412, 278, 550, 508, 147, 517, 416, 73, 275, 431, 77, 350, 457, 5, 551, 292, 573, 582, 421, 575, 178, 108, 598, 493, 171, 484, 160, 597, 73, 516, 200, 95, 30, 577, 475, 360, 586, 86, 198, 128, 598, 305, 203, 208, 442, 49, 280, 502, 433, 48, 254, 526, 185, 540, 324, 319, 47, 346, 251, 374, 10, 65, 105, 240, 105, 19, 449, 538, 13, 521, 562, 100, 93, 361, 500, 341, 333, 85, 398, 98, 92, 504, 5, 521, 7, 281, 509, 224, 54, 444, 537, 26, 102, 250, 105, 566, 126, 109, 566, 521, 58, 29, 335, 467, 320, 470, 70, 182, 300, 557, 169, 66, 379, 181, 567, 443, 347, 321, 50, 85, 223, 30, 251, 390, 390, 66, 173, 112, 336, 9, 265, 373, 57, 165, 197, 533, 376, 368, 494, 596, 235, 586, 154, 266, 466, 171, 15, 400, 174, 352, 58, 548, 156, 217, 84, 475, 244, 128, 80, 22, 400, 535, 491, 210, 461, 321, 284, 93, 251, 234, 80, 540, 56, 445, 303, 84, 515, 403, 345, 575, 515, 231, 38, 263, 358, 137, 411, 486, 245, 127, 269, 373, 23, 508, 14, 427, 404, 173, 355, 49, 137, 233, 268, 467, 160, 593, 7, 432, 268, 563, 566, 17, 588, 398, 227, 474, 122, 457, 279, 215, 2, 36, 479, 152, 323, 453, 294, 264, 214, 471, 97, 175, 484, 200, 188, 489, 218, 255, 96, 502, 196, 576, 145, 389, 96, 49, 479, 161, 355, 440, 124, 569, 336, 262, 314, 381, 545, 445, 299, 131, 474, 383, 187, 28, 404, 76, 358, 481, 528, 351, 181, 68, 389, 23, 191, 261, 457, 247, 496, 329, 566, 554, 460, 458, 201, 156, 568, 197, 335, 515, 470, 474, 38, 386, 502, 18, 432, 497, 542, 343, 519, 575, 357, 136, 203, 114, 5, 364, 201, 593, 218, 45, 192, 434, 102, 423, 360, 266, 499, 279, 358, 589, 236, 200, 195, 510, 278, 219, 31, 527, 151, 407, 396, 228, 46, 150, 452, 421, 363, 575, 102, 247, 357, 430, 86, 596, 544, 427, 11, 542, 45, 421, 65, 596, 482, 47, 576, 533, 220, 534, 50, 347, 597, 195, 544, 398, 0, 139, 355, 542, 362, 70, 68, 288, 78, 399, 542, 96, 295, 179, 164, 490, 404, 266, 415, 113, 165, 105, 26, 319, 566, 412, 527, 492, 599, 329, 477, 288, 242, 27, 31, 130, 410, 20, 380, 239, 239, 350, 85, 343, 146, 226, 564, 81, 553, 177, 146, 563, 280, 483, 8, 315, 488, 509, 451, 36, 34, 386, 342, 299, 570, 275, 137, 267, 568, 432, 78, 132, 172, 1, 394, 59, 210, 181, 368, 204, 519, 468, 588, 367, 175, 338, 375, 392, 63, 306, 65, 327, 343, 511, 163, 458, 597, 291, 472, 187, 239, 151, 302, 325, 21, 587, 590, 593, 94, 108, 171, 269, 5, 178, 439, 440, 19, 37, 74, 36, 574, 71, 326, 477, 281, 173, 448, 201, 557, 580, 512, 151, 412, 599, 576, 270, 225, 589, 67, 579, 431, 256, 581, 168, 158, 202, 281, 244, 419, 484, 417, 496, 173, 576, 109, 198, 227, 70, 537, 99, 445, 245, 110, 269, 51, 79, 50, 431, 554, 34, 270, 351, 354]
```

BUBBLESORT TEST at 600:

```
sorted List: [173, 341, 299, 439, 237, 67, 411, 592, 468, 286, 272, 404, 490, 52, 353, 317, 101, 299, 517, 571, 468, 226, 423, 153, 195, 416, 93, 432, 536, 536, 313, 292, 361, 578, 596, 275, 462, 472, 410, 227, 129, 560, 316, 11, 138, 27, 465, 575, 516, 184, 450, 454, 45, 34, 594, 247, 352, 294, 507, 552, 77, 331, 88, 234, 121, 323, 333, 378, 245, 394, 470, 207, 464, 473, 598, 73, 380, 583, 185, 79, 590, 412, 272, 57, 266, 520, 252, 236, 228, 400, 21, 195, 6, 273, 162, 292, 494, 80, 172, 532, 565, 547, 64, 559, 387, 516, 56, 395, 388, 62, 206, 397, 188, 230, 289, 567, 333, 416, 180, 343, 381, 118, 99, 224, 528, 109, 52, 62, 472, 486, 564, 262, 481, 350, 198, 536, 422, 4, 150, 183, 155, 384, 449, 438, 373, 505, 336, 476, 439, 491, 462, 184, 468, 135, 212, 366, 429, 289, 411, 338, 371, 71, 516, 158, 448, 578, 26, 342, 567, 427, 520, 158, 108, 277, 168, 152, 547, 56, 127, 292, 68, 578, 465, 265, 483, 165, 474, 502, 65, 370, 507, 594, 561, 362, 119, 354, 386, 165, 219, 594, 107, 540, 201, 22, 263, 71, 4, 194, 562, 531, 347, 183, 34, 347, 190, 24, 342, 415, 227, 307, 287, 584, 54, 217, 335, 336, 217, 355, 304, 347, 476, 154, 577, 6, 176, 268, 129, 27, 588, 530, 564, 38, 304, 183, 480, 228, 555, 234, 229, 200, 377, 239, 328, 547, 588, 494, 542, 27, 431, 213, 464, 568, 198, 91, 477, 187, 94, 553, 569, 30, 93, 399, 395, 128, 525, 545, 218, 87, 243, 143, 474, 317, 476, 278, 32, 519, 398, 138, 355, 84, 331, 55, 503, 521, 497, 4, 333, 288, 522, 6, 404, 20, 343, 214, 345, 320, 102, 440, 427, 447, 489, 171, 400, 154, 162, 18, 438, 419, 403, 580, 205, 271, 156, 362, 501, 554, 364, 498, 108, 253, 560, 94, 372, 584, 461, 28, 249, 588, 194, 414, 95, 266, 422, 559, 306, 367, 137, 103, 308, 183, 581, 597, 47, 524, 493, 592, 403, 415, 191, 397, 372, 202, 402, 438, 33, 86, 274, 538, 543, 385, 467, 183, 13, 259, 357, 160, 7, 291, 310, 223, 12, 278, 151, 97, 196, 360, 292, 360, 183, 553, 27, 121, 8, 27, 439, 177, 225, 361, 272, 47, 460, 227, 500, 192, 322, 370, 437, 190, 521, 311, 475, 245, 161, 563, 294, 451, 492, 227, 444, 165, 172, 565, 404, 405, 77, 336, 527, 82, 274, 544, 502, 566, 584, 422, 126, 314, 4, 399, 21, 319, 507, 180, 550, 309, 386, 500, 440, 179, 235, 13, 298, 467, 316, 198, 296, 568, 34, 541, 593, 21, 150, 64, 231, 280, 147, 550, 530, 502, 131, 175, 229, 322, 55, 483, 360, 466, 70, 115, 93, 381, 55, 100, 341, 313, 208, 494, 39, 535, 89, 108, 194, 175, 371, 574, 145, 553, 482, 296, 103, 392, 53, 482, 29, 70, 421, 60, 174, 467, 431, 511, 209, 122, 337, 167, 213, 317, 444, 294, 197, 12, 118, 543, 31, 2, 262, 241, 503, 483, 224, 426, 30, 256, 348, 528, 284, 278, 321, 171, 187, 304, 153, 328, 526, 364, 402, 550, 484, 382, 555, 83, 577, 200, 530, 337, 4, 348, 563, 182, 40, 17, 258, 319, 445, 301, 513, 373, 138, 404, 159, 413, 158, 298, 171, 157, 41, 252, 226, 143, 373, 584, 68, 589, 595, 271, 277, 262, 425, 318, 184, 250, 425, 206, 422, 449, 324, 123, 410, 504, 159, 288]
```

So then I run through different sized arrays, my original problem was fixed thanks to @Mihnea DB but now It won't sort passed the first iteration.

```
  Bubble_Sort reBubble = new Bubble_Sort();
  int[] bubbleArray;    
 for(int N = 100; N<1100; N+=100)
      {
     bubbleArray = new int[N];
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {           
        bubbleArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()*N);            
        }
        System.out.println("BUBBLESORT TEST at " + N);
        reBubble.sort(bubbleArray);
        System.out.println("sorted List: "+ Arrays.toString(bubbleArray));
         }
```

thanks for all your help!

Comment: You might want to test it with a much shorter array.

Comment: @ChthonicProject Yep, still does not work.

Comment: With a short array, it will be much easier for you to step through and debug it and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Kevin, I've restored the mistake from your original question. Please review that the question is still valid and accept one of the answers below pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Note that you don't have to iterate the whole array for each step; the largest value will bubble to the top (hence the name of the algorithm), so after each loop to N, you can reduce N by 1.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma That is actually part of my assignment, to enhance this bubble sort to keep track of the last checked and not have to iterate over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the *smaller than* (`<`) comparison operator, you want to walk the array **from the end towards the beginning**.

I suggest you run your code step by step on this array:

```
[3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 0, 2]
```

After every for iteration you have:

```
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 0, 2]
[4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2]
```

As you can see, the last `2` is misplaced because your assertion (`a[i-1] < a[i]`) still holds.

**Later edit**: If you plan on reusing an instance of the class you should perform the initialisation of `swap = true` inside the sort function.

Comment: Yep I changed it but for arrays larger than 100, it will not sort

Comment: That's really interesting. I'm putting the sort through a loop to increase the size of the array. It works for the first run but does not for the rest. I'll edit my post to add what I'm talking about

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but you cannot reuse that function on multiple arrays as-is. You have to reinitialise `swap` to `true` in-between calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sort(int[] unsorted)
{       
    for(int i=0; i < unsorted.length, i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<unsorted.length-1; j++)
        {
            if(unsorted[j+1]<unsorted[j]) {
                swap(j-1,j);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: for loop is alright but I'm really trying to go by my book which uses a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
if(unsorted[j-1]<unsorted[j])
```

to

```
if(unsorted[j-1] > unsorted[j])
```

Comment: This definitely helped but arrays larger than 100 still does not sort

Comment: oddly enough the array of 100 elements sorts but anything larger like 200 does not.

Comment: I tested with the input you given and the array is sorted